# How can I automate deployment in codedeploy triggered from s3 when I push .war file to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

application run on tomcat and hosted using ECS and selected blue/green deployment type which automatically creates an application in codedeploy
I saperately created a tomcat container, configured it and put my application in webapp folder. then I created image from this and pushed it to AWS ECR.
using this Image I hosted my application in ECS. but I want to automate the deployment using codedeploy when I push the war file to s3.
I dont understand how I can run the script for unzipping the war file and putting unzipped data into webapp folder inside my container.
Thank you for answering

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Nadeem,

You've two options here to Automate your CI/CD Pipeline.I would suggest you to use AWS CodePipeline for this purpose.

1. Trigger CodePipeline whenever you put new image version to ECR (yes
   codepipeline support this out of the box).
2. Trigger Lambda using S3 event. Whenever you upload file to S3, it'll trigger Lambda. Use Lambda to trigger codepipeline then.

Thanks. Let me know if it helped.